# Return rows that match certain Japanese characters in a Series

Tags: python, pandas, character-encoding

I have a pandas dataframe with several columns in Japanese. 
I would like to run a search that returns rows that contain certain Japanese characters.

ex.

```
find_str = 'バッグ'
```

I know I can't just use things like:

```
df[df.col1.str.contains(find_str)] or df[df.col1 == find_str]
```

How would I go about this? Like what encoding would I need to use, etc.?

```
                                           name
0                                                    ヴァラ
1             ALEXANDER WANG(アレキサンダーワン) クラッチバッグ パイソン【中古】
2                                                 ミューズトゥ
3                                                 ミューズトゥ
4                                               ローディーロック
5                                          バブーシュカクリスタルGG
```

I'd run something simple like:

```
df[df.name.str.contains('ゥ')]
```

which should return rows 2 and 3 but instead I get an empty result

Comment: need `df[(df.col1.str.contains(find_str)) | (df.col1 == find_str)]`

Comment: Are you using python2 or 3?

Comment: I am using python 2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me working:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', encoding='utf-8')
find_str = u'バッグ'

m = df['name'].str.contains(find_str)
print (m)
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
Name: name, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Running queries like this results in an empty dataframe for me

Comment: Can you add some sample? 4,5 rows